# Is there a way to remotely get the API_KEY of a connected G Suite user?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Our organization relies on G Suite. We also have an organizational web application, and we want to use Google Calendar API in it.

Specifically, we want to allow connected users to schedule meetings. Unfortunately, it seems it's required to have the user's API_KEY included in all requests made to Google Calendar API.

Is there a way to get a connected user's API_KEY remotely?
Is there any other way to accomplish our goal besides of hardcoding the API_KEY of each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not possible since it would be against the mechanism an API KEY stands for.

You should change your approach and authenticate the users of your web application with their Google accounts. In such a way you will be able to authorize your web application to schedule meetings in behalf of your users. This authentication/authorization protocol is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).

Here you can find some quickstarts to get started with the development: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js